# How to split taxonomy checkboxes on node edit form

Tags: 7, theming

I figured how to do it on node output, but i can not figure how to add css for specific field, in this case taxonomy checkboxes, 50 of them, and split in 4 columns on node edit form.

Comment: `50 of them` have you considered using auto complete tag list as your widget instead of checkboxes?

Comment: Yes, but thats not an option as users do not know what terms are in there prepared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera. This is example for 4 columns for Seven theme.

```
#edit-field-name { 
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with css. You will need to add the following to your Admin theme's css file.

The Drupal default admin theme is **Seven** theme, located in `/core/themes/seven`. You may want to create a sub theme of Seven and use that as your admin theme, so when you upgrade Drupal your css file does not get overridden; thus, you will not lose all your changes.

```
#edit-field-name {
  width:760px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}

#edit-field-name div {
  line-height:1.5em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  width:25%; }
```

replace **-name** with the actual name of your field.

Source: http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/

Comment: I modified CSS a bit and it works like a charm, but strangely only on admin account, although users can use admin theme to add content.

Comment: Did you flush the cache?

Comment: Several times..

Comment: Use the [webdeveloper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) app to check if your css file is loading. In Drupal. you will need to uncheck aggregate css in `admin/config/development/performance` first.

Comment: Yep, its in webdeveloper, and aggregate is off.

Comment: Found out it works in chrome but not in firefox. Using latest versions of all. Using the code:   width:100%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
  columns: 4

Comment: http://csswizardry.com/demos/multiple-column-lists/ works fine for me on firefox... maybe lower the width %?